# How to store user credentials for accessing remote Liferay JSon APIs from user interface in js?

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, liferay

I am currently working with Liferay 6.2-ga1.
I am working on a portlet which contain a table generated with [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) javascript library.

This table has editable cells. Once the user has changed the value within a cell, a callback is called with the change. I would like to call a POST method of my portlet API (let's say POST on /changes which sends a JSon object containing the changes).

To call a method from the rest api, a user must be authenticated. Liferay supports basic http authentication as username:passwd@host:port/api/jsonws/foo/bar

How can I safely retrieve user's name and password without exposing them, in order to call the remote api method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation and playing with the javascript console of my browser, I found out that when the call is made by Javascript from a portlet, you do not need to care about authentication: you will get the priviledges of the user currently logged in.

You can find the list of method you can call at address http://{host}:{port}/api/jsonws

Plus, clicking on the method in the left menu and executing it with some parameters (if needed) will lead you to a view where you can get generated javascript. Using that javascript in your code will allow you to use the REST api, leaving the authentication burden to Liferay.